# Pass function pointer to PostMessage win32/MFC c++

Tags: c++, winapi, function-pointers, win32gui, std-function

I have a template `FunctionHolder` class that holds `std::function` objects with variable parameters and can execute them using an overloaded `operator()`. I want to be able to execute those functions in the context of a specified UI control (in its window procedure) asynchronously (using `PostMessage`), so I do the following:

```
template <typename... Args>
class FunctionHolder {
public:
    using FuncType = std::function<void(Args...)>;

    struct Info {
        FuncType f;
        HWND context;
    };

    void operator()(const Args&... args) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);

        for (auto const& f : functions_) { // I want to exec every stored function
            BindedFuncHelper* s = new BindedFuncHelper{ f.f, args... }; // this is explained later
            PostMessage(f.context, WM_MY_CUSTOM_MESSAGE, (WPARAM)s, 0);
        }

private:
    std::list<Info> functions_;
    mutable std::mutex mutex_;
```

Now, of course in the window procedure of every UI control I process `WM_MY_CUSTOM_MESSAGE`, convert `WPARAM` back to the `BindedFuncHelper` pointer and call the `BindedFuncHelper::call` method. The class looks like this:

```
class BindedFuncHelper {
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    BindedFuncHelper(std::function<void(Args...)> f, Args... args) :
        f_{ std::bind(f, args...) } {}

    void call() {
        f_();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> f_;
};
```

This class allows me to bind the arguments (which are known in the `operator()` overload) to these methods, so that in the window procedure of every UI control I can use the `BindedFuncHelper::call` without knowing the template parameters of the `FunctionHolder` class and its stored functions:

```
        // somewhere in the window proc of the control
        case WM_MY_CUSTOM_MESSAGE:
        {
            BindedFuncHelper* s = (BindedFuncHelper*)wParam;
            // the function inside the BindedFuncHelper object is bound to its parameters
            // therefore I can safely call the call method
            s->call(); 
            delete s;
        }
```

This solution works, but the question is - do I really need the BindedFuncHelper class? Can I somehow send the result of std::bind to the PostMessage method? Or can this approach be somehow problematic and unsafe?

Comment: *"can this approach be somehow problematic and unsafe?"* - Lifetimes are an issue. And with this being C++, you have very little tools of ensuring, that either your arguments or the function object itself live long enough until the posted message can be dispatched.

Comment: A suggestion with what you have, use a std::unique_ptr in the message handler to hold the BindedFuncHelper *, that way if an exception occurs in the handler the BindedFuncHelper will still get deleted.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about the `unique_ptr`, but I intended to use it right in the `operator()` and then use `std::move` to send it as `WPARAM` to the `PostMessage`, but can `unique_ptr` be somehow converted to `WPARAM`? Or my only choice is to create `unique_ptr`in the handler (wnd proc) before i execute the `call` method?

Comment: Passing a unique_ptr as WPARAM would require dynamically allocating the unique_ptr itself and then you would need a unique_ptr<unique_ptr<T>> so no, that is not really a solution.

Comment: Thanks for all of your inputs, I will only modify the BindedFuncHelper to a struct with only one private member and no methods, the core of the approach will remain the same.

Comment: @IInspectable I just wrote a sample app using `std::async` and there are memory leaks caused by unfreed `BindedFuncHelper `objects sent to `PostMessage`, if the application terminates before all the `WM_MY_CUSTOM_MESSAGE` messages are handled (and `BindedFuncHelper` freed). Could you please elaborate on those "very little tools"? How could I possibly delete those objects before the app terminates? Surely there must be a way how dynamically allocated internal win32 structures are deleted in a scenario like this. Many thanks.

Comment: *"Very little tools"* was stated in context of C++. Since you are going through a C interface, things change dramatically. C doesn't have *any* notion of ownership. It's just values, all the way down. If you want to teach C ownership semantics, you're going to have to implement a system on top of it. I'm not aware of any readily available API that helps you in that. If this were me, and my life depended on producing an implementation, I'd probably look into COM. That's the place where all of the most obscure infrastructure hides (like the Running Object Table).